# DDD - Event Sourcing with tree structure

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

That's my example structure:

```
Node 
 - Node 
   - Node (with propety type === leaf)
     + Person
     + Person
 - Node
 - Node
```

`Node`and `Person` are `aggregates` powered by `event sourcing`.
`Leaf` holds `NodeID` and `Person` holds `PersonID`. They do not contain direct reference between eachother.

Now I know how to look in the past for one aggregate and see whole history of Person for example.

1. Get all events that happend before `some time`
2. Do aggregate reconstruction from events

But my question is how to rebuild whole tree structure to see it at some point in the past?

My model:

```
Node
  {
      private string name;
      private string parentNodeID;
      private string type;
      private Array  hiredPersons;  

      Node(string name, string parentNodeID, string type) {
          this.apply(new NodeHasCreated(name, parentNodeID, type));
      }

      public void hirePerson(Person person)
      {
          if(this.type === 'leaf') {
              this.apply(new PersonHasBeenHired(person.id));
          }
      }          

  }
```

What I don't want to achieve is to hold direct reference from node to node. That's why I use parentNodeID.

Comment: how you build structure now? Why you can't just get some initial state and rollup changes?

Comment: I don't. I am in early stage with this project. Just looking for informations.

Initial state? Ye, but I will need to take initial state of root node rollup events and get information about associated nodes and do the same for them. And recursive to the bottom, it will cost much time.
Specially for like 1k nodes.
Well I don't know maybe, my model is just wrong? If you think so, tell me.

Comment: What types of events you will have? Can some types of event be related to many nodes?
You also can have many initial states

Comment: Initial state for Node and Leaf will be always the same. 
I called it leaf just to show node which can have mulitple Persons. 
For real Leaf is just Node with specific `type` property. 

Events which exists in Node are for example:
NodeHasBeenCreated, PersonHasBeenHired (possible only if type === 'leaf'), NodePositionHasChanged, NodeHasBeenDeleted, NodeTypeHasChanged.

Comment: I updated description a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since you are using Event Sourcing I assume that you have denormalized projections for querying purposes and that you aren't querying against the domain model.

That means you currently have a denormalized structure like (simplified):

```
Node (id , type, parent_id)
```

When an event such as `NodeCreated` is handled I assume you currently `INSERT INTO Node` and when you handle `NodeDeleted` you `DELETE FROM Node`, etc.

That allows you to reconstruct up to date representations of your trees, but will not allow temporal representations.

In order to perform temporal queries, you will need a temporal table structure. Some relational databases have built-in support for these, like [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dn935015.aspx). Don't worry if your DB doesn't support that, it's trivial to implement one.

To implement a simple temporal table, you just need to add `start_date datetime NOT NULL` and `end_date datetime NULL` columns to your table. You may also add a constraint to avoid having more than one row where `end_date IS NULL` by AR id.

```
Then where you usually:

did an INSERT you: 
    INSERT INTO tbl (..., start_date) VALUES (..., currentDate)

did an UPDATE you:
    UPDATE tbl SET end_date = GETDATE() WHERE [update predicate] AND end_date IS NULL
    INSERT INTO tbl (..., start_date) VALUES (..., currentDate)
did a DELETE you:
    UPDATE tbl SET end_date = GETDATE() WHERE [delete predicate] AND end_date IS NULL
```

Using this simple approach will allow you to query your data as of any date.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE start_date <= someDate AND (end_date IS NULL OR end_date > someDate)
```

Here's [**an example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44804/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Tree (
    id int NOT NULL,
    parent_id int NULL,
    name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    start_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
    end_date_time datetime NULL
);

GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UN_Tree_id_end_date_time
ON Tree (id, end_date_time)
WHERE end_date_time IS NULL;

INSERT INTO Tree (
    id,
    parent_id,
    name,
    start_date_time,
    end_date_time
)
VALUES
    (1, NULL, 'A', GETDATE(), NULL), -- node A created
    (2, NULL, 'B', GETDATE(), NULL), -- node B created
    (3, 1, 'A.1', GETDATE(), NULL), -- node A.1 created
    (4, 2, 'A.1.1', GETDATE(), NULL); -- node A.1.1 added

-- Node A.1 renamed
UPDATE Tree
SET end_date_time = GETDATE()
WHERE id = 3 AND end_date_time IS NULL;

INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (3, 1, 'A.1_renamed', GETDATE(), NULL);

-- Node A.1.1 removed a day after
UPDATE Tree
SET end_date_time = DATEADD(d, 1, GETDATE())
WHERE id = 4 AND end_date_time IS NULL;


-- Query nodes from root A as of now using a recursive CTE
-- Note: Did not manage to declare a @asOf variable variable in SQL Fiddle
WITH data AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, name
    FROM Tree
    WHERE 
        id = 1
        AND start_date_time <= GETDATE() 
        AND (end_date_time IS NULL OR end_date_time > GETDATE())

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child.id, child.parent_id, child.name
    FROM data d
    INNER JOIN Tree child
        ON 
            child.parent_id = d.id
            AND start_date_time <= GETDATE() 
            AND (end_date_time IS NULL OR end_date_time > GETDATE())
)   
SELECT *
FROM data;
```

[image]

Comment: I am impressed, this is so easy. :)

But I have few concerns:

I will be holding a lot of extra data, which may be never used in read model. 
Also do I need to store events, with such resolution? Because I have all my historic data in Read Model. I could just push events on message queue without storing them in Event Store.

Comment: I am mostly using Postgres it has JSON column type. 
So I guess it would be more efficient to create such temporal table:
CREATE TABLE Tree (
    id int NOT NULL,
    parent_id int NULL,
    data JSON NOT NULL,
    start_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
    end_date_time datetime NULL
);
Data column would hold any extra information like: name, type etc.
It will help me save few bytes for each record. 

What about that?

Comment: The read model should be discardable. The stored events are your single source of truth, everything must be stored on the write side (event store). You can model your read model the way you want, but it should be optimized for queries. You may have multiple representations of the same data if necessary to fulfill various queries.